# Why this ternary operation fails?

Tags: c#

I have 2 pieces of code one using if condition and other using the ? operator.

Both are defined successively within same function scope. But the statement using ? operator throws compile error? Is something wrong with this piece of code.

```
if (IsCount)
       filterParameterOriginTime.Values = new[] { new DateTime(2013, 7, 1).ToString() };
else
       filterParameterOriginTime.Values = new[] { lastPollTime.ToString() };

// IsCount ? filterParameterOriginTime.Values = new[] { new DateTime(2013, 7, 1).ToString() } : filterParameterOriginTime.Values = new[] { lastPollTime.ToString() };
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply, you have the operator backwards, try this:

```
filterParameterOriginTime.Values = IsCount 
    ? new[] { new DateTime(2013, 7, 1).ToString() } 
    : new[] { lastPollTime.ToString() };
```

That said, Henk raises a good point about readability. Aim for readable code versus unnecessarily terse code. I generally tend towards `if` statements in most cases.

Comment: Oh now i realise. It is been a long time since i used that operator. Thanks anyway

Comment: @HenkHolterman The ternary style generally or my particular style not single line? I personally tend towards `if` statements.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Sometimes you have to use the ternary style- for example in the linq to entities, if you want to generate sql CASE.

Comment: The `?:` in general, aggravated by the array initializers.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Have to agree in this case. I've amended my answer with a note towards readability. It is always interesting to hear other devs' views on what is readable and what isn't - creates opportunities to adapt personal coding practices :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
filterParameterOriginTime.Values = IsCount ?  new[] { new DateTime(2013, 7, 1).ToString() } :  new[] { lastPollTime.ToString() };
```